# Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script. Please check the configuration of the 'R' runtime

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016

There are a lot of problem exactly like this. But non of them solve my problem. I installed properly everything. I am using SQL Server 2016 RC1. Here is my `RegisterRExt.log` file.

When i try to run external script i get this error. Here is my script:

```
execute sp_execute_external_script
 @language = N'R',
 @script = N'mysum <- 4+2;
             OutputDataSet <- data.frame(mysum);',
 @input_data_1 = N''
WITH RESULT SETS (([col] int NOT NULL));
```

-

```
Information: 0 : Source directory to pick the RExtension binaries determined to be "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-for-RRE\8.0\R-3.2.2\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\".
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:22:56.0402714Z
 Information: 0 : Connecting to SQL server...
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:22:56.0558982Z
 Information: 0 : Sql server binn directory is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS16\MSSQL\Binn".
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:22:56.1052780Z
 Information: 0 : Sql server log directory is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS16\MSSQL\Log".
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:22:56.1088796Z
 Information: 0 : Creating user account pool...
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:22:56.1088796Z
 Information: 0 : Creating user accounts.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:22:56.1088796Z
 Information: 0 : Created SQL login for the R SQL user group DESKTOP-A30IBLC\SQLRUserGroupSQLEXPRESS16
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.1721674Z
 Information: 0 : Adding firewall rule for user account pool.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.1721674Z
 Information: 0 : Creating working directory for user accounts.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.2034223Z
 Information: 0 : Saving user account configuration.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.2513028Z
 Information: 0 : User account pool with 20 users created.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.2569751Z
 Information: 0 : R installation found at C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-for-RRE\8.0\R-3.2.2.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.2569751Z
 Information: 0 : MPI installation found at C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.2569751Z
 Information: 0 : Settings file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS16\MSSQL\Binn\rlauncher.config created.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.2726036Z
 Information: 0 : Stopping service MSSQLLaunchpad$SQLEXPRESS16...
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.2882280Z
 Information: 0 : Stopping service MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS16...
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.2882280Z
 Information: 0 : Copied RLauncher.dll from C:\Program Files\Microsoft\MRO-for-RRE\8.0\R-3.2.2\library\RevoScaleR\rxLibs\x64\ to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS16\MSSQL\Binn.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.5649722Z
 Information: 0 : Starting service MSSQLLaunchpad$SQLEXPRESS16...
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:32.5649722Z
 Information: 0 : R extensibility installed successfully.
    DateTime=2016-03-31T08:24:33.7295591Z
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is that the question is ill-received because it is not very descriptive. What exactly did you do that caused this error? Could you give some links to the other questions? Could you provide some more context? You may want to read [how to ask a question on Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Edit: To the people who downvote without leaving comments: while you may not like the question, it's usually better to explain what you don't like about it. This helps OP for the future as well.

Comment: @Laterow thank you, a lot. I am in a hurry (doing an internship ) so i forgot the put my script.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the log, it does not look like there aren't any obvious issues with the installation. Can you share error logs from following locations?

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS16\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog\rlauncher.log"

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS16\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog\EXTLAUNCHERRORLOG"

Comment: The logs are not accessible. Can you share just the errors portion from these logs?

Answer (score 0):

Please note SQL Server 2016 RC2 is now [available for download](https://technet.microsoft.com/evalcenter/mt130694). RC2 features the [integrated setup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt604847.aspx) of all components. You can upgrade the R components using [these instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt653951.aspx).